# Is stripping backslashes enough to sanitize user generated input?

Tags: security

If I accept any input from the scary Internet to generate first a tex file and then a pdf using XeTeX in a server, is it enough to remove all backslashes and escape all the reserved characters `#, %, $, _, ^, &, {, }` as `\#, \%, etc` to be in the safe side?

Edit:

The backslash-removal and character-escaping is done just in the *content* part of the file, for instance:

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle

This is the user generated input with characters like \#, \%.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you just tell TeX to treat it as a string?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question to make it clear that the user generated input is just a part of the tex file.

Comment: With an engine like `pdflatex` you're pretty safe, unless you enable shell escapes and such.

Comment: Though I guess that directives can be used to change the engine if you compile it from an editor.

Comment: I don't understand why that would stop you treating it as a string. So long as the user-generated bit isn't to have anything which does anything, why can't you treat it as a string? @JPi Better to disable shell escape altogether.

Comment: I'm not sure you get anything sensible if you strip all backslashes from the input. What if the user wants to typeset a fraction? `$\frac{1}{3}$` would become `\$frac\{1\}\{3\}\$`.

Comment: If you just want to include something verbatim, then include it between `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` (in this case you have to make sure that the text does not contain a line with `\end{verbatim}`), or even better, put the external text into a file and include it verbatim.

Comment: @cfr How do you tell TeX to treat it as a string?

Comment: Well, `\string`. But only for shortish things, of course. Otherwise `verbatim` or whatever.

Comment: @Victor I was going to answer this question but there is a lot I don't know. Anyway, if you don't care about how the content is typeset (as seems to be the case), then a different solution I would use, instead of escaping with backslashes, is to change the category code of every character (from 0 to 255) to "letter" (or at least, something innocuous). Then you can be sure that TeX will not treat it as a command, say. However, I don't know whether there exist any crashes or the like in TeX or XeTeX. Probably unlikely for plain TeX at least, but you may want to compile and run with afl-fuzz say.